# CSS not being imported in vite single spa root app

Tags: vite, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-react

I am migrating my CRA + Craco microfrontend app to vite using `vite-plugin-single-spa`. I have converted the root app as well in vite using the same plugin.

The problem I am facing is css is not being imported when loading my microfrontend into the root app with default built settings.

Root app `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import vitePluginSingleSpa from "vite-plugin-single-spa";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    vitePluginSingleSpa({
      type: "root",
      imo: "2.4.2",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Microfrontend `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import vitePluginSingleSpa from "vite-plugin-single-spa";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default ({ mode }) => {
  // load app-level env vars to node-level env vars.
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd() )};

  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      react(),
      tsconfigPaths(),
      vitePluginSingleSpa({
        type: "mife",
        serverPort: 4101,
        spaEntryPoints: "src/spa.jsx",
        projectId: 'mifeA',
        cssStrategy: 'singleMife',
      }),
    ],
    base: process.env.VITE_BASE_URL
  });
}
```

microfrontend spa entry point `src/spa.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react';
import { cssLifecycleFactory } from 'vite-plugin-single-spa/ex';

import App from './App'

const lc = singleSpaReact({
    React,
    ReactDOMClient,
    rootComponent: App,
    errorBoundary() {
        return <div>Error</div>
    }
});

const cssLc = cssLifecycleFactory('spa');
export const bootstrap = [cssLc.bootstrap, lc.bootstrap];
export const mount = [cssLc.mount, lc.mount];
export const unmount = [cssLc.unmount, lc.unmount];
```

The interesting thing is when I am adding this piece in the vite.config.js file, css does get imported in the root app. The difference I see is the default build settings divide the js and css files in chunks, whereas this build configs, builds the app in a single js file and a single css file.

```
build: {
   rollupOptions: {
     output: {
          manualChunks: undefined,
          inlineDynamicImports: true,
     }
  }
}
```

Another solution I found was using `vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js` this plugin which injects all css into js files.

Though I have found couple of solutions, Ideally I would like to stick to css and chunks of js. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**PS: I didn't find any tag related to `vite-single-plugin-spa`. If anyone with 1500+ reputations can create a new tag, it would help reach this question to correct community members**

Comment: Hello.  I made `vite-plugin-single-spa`.  I roam here from time to time, but best if you use [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/WJSoftware/vite-plugin-single-spa/discussions).

Comment: I read the code you show and I see nothing commented.  I only see one comment line and is not code.

Comment: @JoséRamírez sorry for mis communication, the last code piece is what worked i.e., when the build is done and only generate single js and cs file, (no chunks). Then only the css gets imported. And I will create a issue for it on github. Thanks